# Exporting DataGridView to Excel without formatting change

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, date, datagridview

I am creating a Windows application where I export data from DataGridView to Excel. The issue is when it's exported the data format changes, for example the data format in the grid is `dd/mm/yyyy` but it's exported as `dd/mm/yyyy tt:mm` and there are some numbers like `2.10` that become on the Excel `2.1`:

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.csv)|*.csv";
        sfd.FileName = "GE.csv";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
            ToCsV(dataGridView2, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name 


        }
        textBox3.Text = sfd.FileName;
        button5.Visible = true;
    }
    private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Is there any way around that?

Update :

i have changed the date filedss on the DB to varchar and it worked, but the still the number lose the last decimel if its zero, i tried to extract it to txt file it comes out with the zero but when i open the text with excel it losses the zero

Comment: Data formatting is a property of Excel itself. You're exporting to csv in which you cannot dictate how Excel will format it.

Comment: when i open it as a text it have the same wrong formate and tried to change the code to sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (.xls)|.xls"; sfd.FileName = "GE.xls"; still chaning the format

Comment: i changed the date type on the DB to varchar and it worked but still have the dicemel issue